# Install packages from terminal while other applications are running?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, google-chrome

Sometimes I find myself installing packages from terminal while chrome is running (because I m following the instructions on how to install). Sometimes some other applications may also be running or just several chrome tabs including one playing internet radio. Is that a bad practice that can cause problems? Should I be closing other applications before installing packages?

Comment: I have accepted answers to questions I asked before, for example [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/726892/tor-command-is-not-starting-tor-browser). It's only been 15 hours till Videonauth answered, give me some time to log in again first :(

Comment: Oops... Sorry! :/  Copied the wrong canned comment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this is not Windows it is perfectly safe to install anything without closing other applications, opened applications are available as a copy inside the `/proc` folder (remember everything on Linux is a file, even processes). So you can install even an upgrade of your Browser while it is running, but a change will only happen in that moment when you choose to close all occurrences of your browser.

Comment: So if a malware force hidden instances to run software will never update?

Comment: Linux is not Windows. There are no hidden instances, it may only be a process not showing up anything in a GUI (X server). Everything is visible in the process list. Malware as typically known from the Windows world in hardly a matter in Linux.