# Tor Browser Launcher does not download Tor Browser

Tags: downloads, tor, signature, downloaders, tor-browser

I have installed Tor Browser Launcher:

```
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```

but when I try to run Tor Browser the download always fail:

[image: Tor Browser failed download screenshot]

Note: other downloads finish properly and I can correctly verify signatures, so apparently there is problem with Tor Browser download rather than attack on the system.

For your info here is Tor Browser Launcher config:

[image: Tor Browser Launcher settings]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu) Read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu/895999#895999

Comment: Check [`gpg --version`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181117/tor-browser-installation-hangs-on-verifying-signature), it has to be 2.2.17 or newer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tor browser not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316105/tor-browser-not-opening)

Answer (score 0):

i got the same thing but never explored why or how to fix. I had ubuntu.podcast playing at the moment I got the error where they were talking about the "software boutique", so I gave it a try and presto - i had tor browser installed.  if no-one else can answer as to a fix; you could always try my lazy-ass work-around

[software boutique is a new-ish [ubuntu-mate] ubuntu-software-centre that contains common or best-in-class type apps, skipping many less-used ones]

addendum:  if trying this, un-install current version first; as I was left with two menu items & icons (one for fully-installed by boutique, and other failed by apt-get); so its probably quicker to have none-installed first instead of working out which is which to un-install the partially-installed-one..

Comment: People say that Tor Browser installed with Software Centre or apt-get is outdated and gets updated not-so-often. On another machine I just downloaded the bundle from Tor Project site, however I still wonder why Launcher does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Installation problems with the Ubuntu Boutique (16.04 LTS). I went to the Tor project home and followed their instructions. Very smooth.  There was a note not to run the launcher as root. This seems the problem with the Ubuntu Software Boutique.

Hope this helps,

Yves