# Use Tor Browser on Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a MacBook Air

Tags: macbook, browser, tor

I have my Ubuntu (22.04 Jammy Jellyfish) running on a MacBook Air.
I was trying to install Tor there but it seems like I can't launch it.

I have done everything OK, but it simply doesn't launch when calling from terminal or launching via doubleclick.

I downloaded from here: [torproject.org/download](https://torproject.org/download) and followed instructions from here: [tb-manual.torproject.org/installation](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/installation).

I chose and installed Tor for Linux.
Verified the signature, extracted the file, marked the

> start-tor-browser.desktop

file as executable.

I right-click and hit "run as a program" and I see the Terminal quickly flashing but nothing else happens thereafter

Anyone can think of a workaround/solution?

I've tried also Tor Browser Launcher, but when clicking on "Install Tor Browser" it crashes.

Ideas?

Comment: How did you install Tor Browser? Is it a snap?

Comment: Via terminal following all the instrucions on the official Tor project website. How do I check if it's a snap (it shouldn't)

Comment: Can you give a link?

Comment: Did you download Tor for Mac or for Linux? What were the commands?

Comment: Sure: downloaded from here: https://www.torproject.org/download/ and followed instructions from here: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/installation/. I installed Tor for Linux. Verified the signature, extracted the file, marked the start-tor-browser.desktop file as executable. I right-click and hit "run as a program" and I see the Terminal quickly flashing but nothing else happens thereafter

Comment: So what exactly did you do? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tor browser not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316105/tor-browser-not-opening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way probably due to what was commented here:

> torbrowser-launcher is plagued by a Python 3.10 related bug. It crashes on run as is currently. Known issue with a fix submitted upstream but not merged yet

In order to use the self-contained "TOR bundle" you must open a terminal to the extracted folder and run:

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! Let's then wait for the Python 3.1 bug to be addressed and do this in the meantime. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install Tor Browser using `apt`.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher
```

and you are done.

Comment: Dude. No, that doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means nothing. Does it install? And it will install to another place. You wont start it in that folder where you downloaded it previously.

Comment: As said in my original question: "I've tried also Tor Browser Launcher, but when clicking on "Install Tor Browser" it crashes".

Comment: How did you try it? I gave you a command, There is nothing to click there. After you execute it, you'll have Tor Browser among your applications.

Comment: I used the Ubuntu Software. When I launch that I get what I said. I aslo tried you command but nothing happened

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened"? What was the output?

Comment: @Pilot6 torbrowser-launcher is plagued by a Python 3.10 related bug.  It crashes on run as is currently.  Known issue with a fix submitted upstream but not merged yet.